# Is wordnet.lookup an async function? Trying to build an array of synonyms for each word in a sentence with wordnet and natural

Tags: javascript, nlp, wordnet

So I'm trying to use wordnet for the first time to build a text recognition script for a small text based adventure game project I'm working on.  Right now, I have this code to try and build an object that consists of each word as a key and each synonym to that word as an array attached to that key:

```
const natural = require('natural');
const wordnet = new natural.WordNet();

let s = "Inspect the room";
function resultCheck(sentence) {
    a = sentence.split(' ');
    let sObj = {};
    a.forEach(word => {
        sObj[word] = [];
        wordnet.lookup(word, function (details) {
            details.forEach(function (detail) {
                sObj[word].push(detail.synonyms);
            });
            sObj[word] = sObj[word].join().split(',');
            console.log(sObj);
        });
    });
    return sObj;
}
let newOb = resultCheck(s);
console.log(newOb);
```

The console logs the arrays of synonyms being built correctly, but the returning object is just the keys with empty arrays.  I tried using async/await in a few ways as well with no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pre-ES6 JS. It’s not async in the sense of async/await or promise-based. [src](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural/blob/master/lib/natural/wordnet/wordnet.js) But it is async in that is full of recursive callbacks.

EDIT: How to do what you want:

Though I use const and arrow functions, this is very old school Javascript, in that you have to enforce execution order by nesting callbacks. Also, sorry for adding lodash, but I just always turn to it; I don't know how to use JS without it.

```js
const natural = require('natural');
const _ = require('lodash')


const wordnet = new natural.WordNet();
const tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer();


const sent = "Welcome to callback hell."
const setSyns = {}

const handleLookup = (word, syns) => {
    setSyns[word] = syns
}

const doLast = () => {
    console.log(setSyns)
}

// callback to wordnet.lookup gets passed an array of objects
// one property of which is `synonyms`

// also, use a tokenizer

tokenizer.tokenize(sent).forEach((word, idx, words) => {
    wordnet.lookup(word, x => {
        synsList = _.flatMapDeep(x, y => y.synonyms)
        handleLookup(word, _.uniq(synsList))
        if (idx == words.length - 1) {
            doLast()
        }
    })
})

console.log(setSyns)  // logs {} because this is executed before the loop is done
```

Comment: Is there a work around to make this work in ES6 JS?  Sorry I'm still new to programming and was trying to branch out a bit.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: @JoshDowns I added working code to do what you want. Hopefully it makes sense. If so, upvote and accept; LMK if not.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  It mostly makes sense to me.  I haven't worked with lodash or tokenizer yet, so I'm going to have to do some research on to what they do so I can further understand what's going on.  Either way, this is a huge help.  I start a full time coding bootcamp on Monday, but I haven't really been able to put any of this down since I started getting into it.

Comment: Tokenizing is the process of turning a string into a list of tokens (smaller strings). You were doing it with string.split(“ “), but that is not ideal, bc for example it doesn’t separate punctuation like periods and commas. Lodash is a very common JS utilities library. JS is a better language than it was 10 years ago, but it’s still missing some things that are nice to have, and I am used to getting them from lodash.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  If you don't mind I have one last question.  Is tokenizing part of the Lodash library?  When I try to research it the results keep bringing up the split method.

Comment: No, in the fourth line of code, you can see that it comes from Natural. Tokenization is pretty much always step one of dealing with natural language

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  I saw tokenizer and went straight to google and must have missread that line.  Either way, this is all great and I really appreciate it!